# How do I refresh the auto-completion in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-cdt

I'm am using eclipse-cdt and the auto-completion feature works fine.
But after I changed the interface of a class the auto-completion shows the new function as well as the old one which aren't even there anymore.

Refreshing the project has no effect. Neither does a restart of eclipse and I can't seem to find out how I refresh the index that is obviously kept somewhere to speed up the auto-completion feature.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just have to refresh the internal CDT index.
To do so right click on your C/C++ project > Index > Rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Try running `eclipse -clean` from your Eclipse directory (`eclipse.exe -clean` on Windows, or `./eclipse -clean` on Mac or Linux). That'll wipe a few cache files and hopefully fix your auto-completion.

Comment: The -clean option will clear all caches at the OSGI level. It has nothing to do with the CDT auto-completion index! (See option description at the following address http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html?view=co)